# Having units in Google Spreadsheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

I want to be able to input plain numbers like `200`, or `3000` and have the cell display `200g`, `3kg`, etc... 
But still be able to add the values in the cells. So if I add the two above I'd get `3.2kg` on the result cell.

I suspect this is not possible, but is it?

Comment: What would be really nice is a spreadsheet which also calculated units.

So you would get an error if you tried to add meter and liter.

And m * m giving m^2

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Does not manage the automatic division by 1000 for kilogrammes but perhaps of some use (better than nothing?)

In New Google Sheets, `Format > Number > More Formats > Custom Number Format` and Apply:

```
0,0 g
```

Comment: I can't seem to add a unit of 2 or more characters, i.e. `km` is not valid.

Comment: @Morgoth It works if you double-quote the unit: 0,0 "km"

Comment: Cool, thanks all. e.g. formats working for me 0.0"km" or 0.0"m"

Answer (score 4):

I found it.

Format > Number > More Formats > Custom Number Format
then enter: `. "lbs"`

If you want two decimal points then it would be: `.00 "lbs"`

Putting whatever you want in quotes allows you to create custom units of measurement.

Answer (score 1):

There is an add-on that does this called [LegendSheet](https://legendsheet.com/). However, you don't have the number and the unit in the same cell rather you have to put them side by side. But it handles all the unit conversions such that you could do something like this:

```
  | A   | B    | C     | D | E                     |
--+-----+------+-------+---+-----------------------+
1 | 3.0 | [k]g | 200.0 | g | =LS_QADD(A1:B1,C1:D1) |
```

And the result in `E1` will be `3.2 [k]g`. Note that you have to use the brackets for unit prefixes. There is a help video on on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K6Nvw2q889Q) that shows you can also do subtraction, multiplication and division and raise to a power numbers with units. It is a paid add-on, but you get a good amount of free uses per day that I find to be sufficient for my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to resurect this very old question but I was looking to do the same thing and could not find the answer anywhere. My missus is useless when it comes to multiplying a recipe from her books to cover the number of people she is cooking for so i created a spreadsheet for her to enter the number of people the recipe is aimed at and the number of people se is cooking for and calculate the weights. of course the recipies all use different measurements and I wanted to account for them all.

Here is what i ended up doing...

first format the column you want to enter the values into as plain text

```
format > number > plain text
```

This will allow a number without units to work with the following regex functions

add a few columns beside the column you want to enter your value into...
in these columns add the formulas -

```
column C. =VALUE(REGEXREPLACE(B7,"[^[:digit:].]", ""))

column D. =REGEXREPLACE(B7,"[^[:alpha:]]", "")
```

this will split the entered measurement into its value and unit components.

now create a conversion table on a separate sheet that contains the following -

| unit | conversion rate | base unit | base increment | multiplier |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| g | 1 | g | kg | 1000 |
| kg | 1000 | g | kg | 1000 |
| lb | 454 | g | kg | 1000 |
| lbs | 454 | g | kg | 1000 |
| oz | 28 | g | kg | 1000 |
| ml | 1 | ml | L | 1000 |
| L | 1000 | ml | L | 1000 |
| pt | 568 | ml | L | 1000 |
| qt | 1137 | ml | L | 1000 |
| floz | 29 | ml | L | 1000 |
| tsp | 1 | tsp | tbsp | 3 |
| tbsp | 1 | tbsp | tbsp | 1 |
| ... |  |  |  |  |

add whatever conversions you want on here

back on the main sheet continue adding columns to do the lookups

```
column E. =INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$C$99,MATCH(D7,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$99,0),3)
```

this gets the base unit

```
column F. =if(E7="",1,INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$C$99,MATCH(D7,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$99,0),2))
```

gets the conversion rate (defaults to 1 if the unit entered is unknown)

```
column G. =F7*C7
```

Gets the total base qty for the recipe

```
column H. =round((G7/$K$3)*$K$4)
```

adjust for the number of people being served (k3 holds the number servings on the recipe, k4 holds the number of servings required)

```
column I. =if(E7="","",INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$E$99,MATCH(D8,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$99,0),4))

column J. =if(E7="",1,INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$E$99,MATCH(D7,Sheet2!$A$2:$A$99,0),5))
```

Gets the values needed to convert to the highest denomination of the measurement

```
column K. =if(H12/J12 >= 1,H12/J12 & " " & if(I12="",D12,I12), H12 & " " & E12)
```

this is the actual value we have been looking for. It checks if the conversion to the higher denomination is greater or equal to 1. If so it uses the higher denomination - otherwise it uses the base denomination.

Hide columns C - J and this is what you get -

| Recipe Multiplier |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |
| recipe servings |  | 4 |
| req servings |  | 6 |
|  |  |  |
| **ingredient** | **recipe qty** | **total qty** |
| eggs | 2 | 3 |
| sugar | 6 oz | 252 g |
| milk | 10 fl oz | 435 ml |
| cinnamon | 1 tsp | 2 tsp |
| flour | 750 g | 1.125 kg |

Comment: I like it.  I would put the units as a select list to the right of the number values which would serve to allow the user to manipulate the ending unit, and also avoid typos in the beginning units.  Nicely done!

Answer (score -1):

you can add to any cell: `& "unit"`

Comment: A description would be more helpful.

Comment: The OP still wants to be able to add the cells up, though.

Comment: Off topic but very helpful (we can use this to add the unit directly in the formula eg: `(17+36)/3 & "€"`