# SI units in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-cell-format

In Google Sheets, I work with data spanning a few orders of magnitude, like mm (millimeter), µm (micrometer), and nm (nanometer). I wrote this formula for a custom number format using conditional rules:

> [>=1000000]0.00,, "mM";[>=1000]0.00, "µM";0.00 "nM"

In this formula, nanometers are the default unit, so the data needs to be input in terms of nanometers. This means that:

> 1 is displayed as "1.00 nm"
> 1000 is displayed as "1.00 µm"
> 1000000 is displayed as "1.00 mm"

However, most of the data I work with is in the micrometer range, so I want to find a way to make micrometers the default unit for convenience. This would mean that:

> 0.001 should be displayed as "1.00 nm"
> 1 should be displayed as "1.00 µm"
> 1000 should be displayed as "1.00 mm"

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se] Please show what you have tried to adapt your formula to your needs.

Comment: Related: [Utilize SI units in Google Sheets](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/135778/196152)